# Send HTTP 201 response with Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I would like to send a 201 HTTP response after a resource is created along with its location.

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: http://www.example.org/myresource/12546
```

How do you define your `@ApiMethod`?

Comment: It's currently not possible.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [the Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/exceptions):

> HTTP 200 is typically assumed by Endpoints if the API method returns
>   successfully. If the API method response type is void or the return
>   value of the API method is null , HTTP 204 will be set instead. HTTP
>   2xx codes should not be used in custom exception classes.

having said that if you still need to return a 201 code, you can hack a service exception to provide that.

```
public class EverythingOKException extends ServiceException {
    public EverythingOKException(String message) {
        super(201, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, even though it makes me sad. The advertisement was "RESTful API". Returning 201 upon creation of a new resource is mandatory for a truly RESTful interface. -1 on Google's part here.